# Simple CSS. Horizontal menu doesn't keep its length when position: fixed

Tags: html, css

I'm at my first HTML and CSS project and the code has a mind of its own!

So... I did a horizontal menu. It displays really cool, with the background color on the entire page width.

But when I want to make it position: fixed, so that it stays on the page when the width is small, the background color disappears from the width.

The HTML:

```html
    <div class="nav">
   <ul>
  <li class="selected"><a href="tema.html">Job Description Details</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Audit Trail</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Files</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

The CSS without the fixed position, which works great.

```css
.nav {
    background-color:  #488AC7;
 margin:            none;
}

.nav ul {
 margin:            0px;
 list-style-type:   none;
 padding:           5px 0px 5px 0px;
}


.nav ul li {
 display:           inline;
 padding:           5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.nav ul li a:link, .nav ul li a:visited {
 color:             #F0FFFF;
 border-bottom:     none;
 font-weight:       bold;
}

.nav ul li.selected {
    background-color:   #F0FFFF;
    border-bottom:      none; 
}

.nav ul li.selected a:link, .nav ul li.selected a:visited {
    color:              #488AC7;
}
```

and the CSS code which makes the color go away:

```css
.nav ul {
 margin:            0px;
 list-style-type:   none;
 padding:           5px 0px 5px 0px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: what exactly you want to accomplish with fixed position? you can apply it to nav class instead of ul it will make it fix. Also you can use top, left to determine where to position in into the page

Comment: I've tried applying it to the nav class but it's the same result - the background color stops going the full width and only sticks to the actual names width. The scope is.. well... the homework requirement said it needs to be fixed. So it sticks to the page when scrolling right.

Comment: You need to provide a width to the nav https://jsfiddle.net/2j8s8xfz/

Comment: it works!!!! Bless you - the width 100%, d'oh. Thank youuuuu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ... this will work when position is `fixed`

```
.nav {
    background-color:  #488AC7;
    margin: none;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

fix yor `.nav` not the `ul`.
if you want try this complete code, just copy and paste.then run

```
<html>

     <head>
      <title></title>
     </head>

    <style type="text/css">

     body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

     }

    div.mynavbar{
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1%;
        background-color: black;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;

    }

     ul li{
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
        width: auto;
        margin: 5%;


     }

    ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 20px;
        color:white;
    }

    ul li a:hover{
        color: red;
    }

    </style>


     <body>

     <div class="mynavbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="selected"><a href="tema.html">Job Description Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Audit Trail</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Files</a></li>
          </ul>
     </div>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Graham!!! Wow, so many helpful people here.. Grateful for each and every answer.

Comment: I've clicked on the up arrow, of course, but it said I need a reputation > 15 before it's public. In my heart, it's public though :)

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed;` is supposed to fix the position of the element relative to the viewport, regardless scroll. So you will have to provide a width to the element.

View the entire working code at https://jsfiddle.net/2j8s8xfz/1/

```css
body{
  min-height:900px;
}
.nav {
    background-color:  #488AC7;
 margin:            none;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}

.nav ul {
 margin:            0px;
 list-style-type:   none;
 padding:           5px 0px 5px 0px;
}


.nav ul li {
 display:           inline;
 padding:           5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.nav ul li a:link, .nav ul li a:visited {
 color:             #F0FFFF;
 border-bottom:     none;
 font-weight:       bold;
}

.nav ul li.selected {
    background-color:   #F0FFFF;
    border-bottom:      none; 
}

.nav ul li.selected a:link, .nav ul li.selected a:visited {
    color:              #488AC7;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
  <li class="selected"><a href="tema.html">Job Description Details</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Audit Trail</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Files</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</body>
```

Read more about positioning at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: @EmmaZ Please accept the answer if it works. Cheers :)

Comment: you mean by clicking on the up arrow? or on the 'check', whatever the name is, below the down arrow?

Answer (score 0):

update nav class:

```
.nav {
    background-color:#488AC7;
    margin:none
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: width:100%. I've learned that but I can't believe I've forgotten about it! So many thanks, ClearBoth!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add only width: 100%; to ul you will get background color over full width of page

```css
.nav ul {
 margin:            0px;
 list-style-type:   none;
 padding:           5px 0px 5px 0px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 0px; 
    width: 100%;
}
```